# dev.ratio in glmnet

Tags: r, r-squared, glmnet

After running `glmnet` I can get a pseudo R-squared with `glmnet.fit$dev.ratio`. Does this take into account the complexity of the model? In other words, is `dev.ratio`equivalent to R-squared or adjusted R-squared?